# What DataGrip SQL Dialect is closest to BigQuery STANDARD SQL (SQL 2011)

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

Google claims that BigQuery Standard SQL is closest to SQL 2011. When using DataGrip (or similar platform), what SQL Dialect would match closest to the Standard SQL dialect that BigQuery uses?

- DB2
- Derby
- H2
- HSQLDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- Oracle SQL*Plus
- PostgreSQL
- SQL Server
- SQL92
- SQLite
- Sybase

Comment: Follow (and upvote) this DataGrip issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3142

Answer (score 4):

This question will probably generate mostly opinion-based answers, as a heads up. Of the query engines you listed, you will probably find that BigQuery's standard SQL is closest to PostgreSQL, since PostgreSQL generally follows the SQL standard closely.

Comment: curious why this is an opinion-based answer? perhaps someone with more knowledge of the BigQuery internals knows if Google modeled the Standard SQL on one of the other dialects (I'd agree it's likely PostgreSQL)

Comment: It is opinion-based not due to the actual implementation of google, it is opinion based due to not existing an objective way of measuring similitude between two SQL flavors